# Find the ratio $PA:AT$

Tags: geometry

$PQRS$ is a parallelogram.

We know that $T\in{QR}$, $\frac{QT}{TR}=\frac{3}{2}$ and that $A=PT\cap QS$.

We have to find the ratio $\frac{PA}{AT}$.

I know this is a primary level question, but I would like to know if there are some different methods for solving it.

Comment: I'm too lazy to draw a figure but isn't $PA:AT=PS:QT=5:3$ using similar triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by metacompactness in the comments, the triangles $QAT$ and $SAP$ are similar since they have three congruent angles, so we have:
$$\frac{PA}{AT}=\frac{PS}{QT}=\frac{QR}{QT}=\frac{5}{3}.$$
An interesting technique for solving such problems is to consider that affine maps preserve the ratios between the lengths of segments on the same line, so it is possible to assume without loss of generality that $PQRS$ is a square, with:
$$P=(0,0),\quad Q=(1,0),\quad R=(1,1),\quad S=(0,1).$$
By this way we have that the equation of the $PT$-line is $y=\frac{3}{5}x$ while the equation of the $QS$-line is $y=1-x$. These two lines intersects in:
$$ A=\left(\frac{5}{8},\frac{3}{8}\right),$$
and the same conclusion follows.
[image]